# What technique should I use to prevent unpermitted access to my REST API

Tags: web-application, rest, permissions

I need to build an REST API that can be accessed via HTTPS when given valid credentials.

How should I implement those credentials?

I am looking for advice whether I should use plain old passwords, or tokens or somethings else, and why I should do so.

I do not look for a tutorial on how to set up this (even though I won't be mad if provided any)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of options and you should pick the best one based on your requirements.  Authentication systems aimed at automated systems have different usability requirements than users.

For example, users generally don't want to present their password with every request or handle long, complicated passwords.  The code calling your API doesn't have those issues.

Internally you should probably store api tokens or passwords the same way you do user passwords: salt them with a long random value and hash them with a reasonable algorithm.

You also have the option of using client certificates that are trusted by your app.  More complicated to set up but you don't have to pass the sensitive credentials materials between systems.

Again, all of these options should be vetted against the security requirements of the system.  If you're securing a bank or missile launch codes you're going to want to have higher standards than the API for a casual website.

Comment: Imagine missiles being launched via HTTP request... SCNR

Thanks so far!